# Lua C: How would I use the Lua source code to create a Lua interpreter that will execute given blocks of Lua code?

Tags: c, api, compiler-construction, lua

I would like to have a detailed explanation.

How would I use the Lua source code to create a Lua interpreter that will execute given blocks of Lua code? The blocks of Lua code would be sent as a `char`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need a call to `lua_load` to compile the block of code, and then a call to `lua_call` to run it.  For a really good example of how this is done, take a look at the [example provided here:](http://www.lua.org/pil/24.1.html).

The first argument to any Lua api function is always an interpreter state, which is the return value of `lua_open()`

The example actually uses `luaL_loadbuffer` which wraps the call to `lua_load` to make compiling a c string a bit easier.  you can read how to use it in the chapter of the reference manual that covers the [The Auxiliary Library](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#4).  This leaves a lua *chunk* at the top of the lua stack, which can then be invoked with `lua_call`, but the example uses `lua_pcall`, which provides a bit of error trapping.  since the chunk you just compiled doesn't take any arguments (it's a chunk not a function) and doesn't have any return value you'd be interested in, and you want to see the error exactly as it was produced, all of the arguments besides the first (which is always the lua interpreter state) can be zeros.

Comment: How would I satisfy the args in this function?

Comment: See my answer to your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272231/how-does-lua-load-work/4272661#4272661

Answer (score 0):

http://www.lua.org/manual/2.1/subsection3_7_6.html

http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2006-10/msg00405.html an example

http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/264 c++, same type thing

This will tell you how to call Lua from C.