# How does `lua_load()` work?

Tags: c, function, lua, call

How would I load a chunk of Lua code as a `char` and run it using this function? If not, what other function can I use and how does `lua_load()` work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `luaL_dofile` and `luaL_dostring` to load and run Lua code. Read their definitions in `lauxlib.h` to see how these are implemented in terms of lower-level primitives.
To learn how `lua_load` works, read the code of `luaL_loadfile` and `luaL_loadstring`.